# Error Unorderable Types. Select rows where on hdf5 files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I work with python 3.5 and I have the next problem to import some datas from a hdf5 files.

I will show a very simple example which resume what happen. I have created a small dataframe and I have inserted it into a hdf5 files. Then I have tried to select from this hdf5 file the rows which have on the column "A" a value less that 1. So I get the error:

"Type error: unorderable types: str() < int()"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf7S7.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import h5py
from pandas import DataFrame, HDFStore

def test_conected():
hdf_nombre_archivo ="1_Archivo.h5"
hdf = HDFStore(hdf_nombre_archivo)

np.random.seed(1234)
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4), index=index, columns=
['A', 'B','C','F'])
print(df)
with h5py.File(hdf_nombre_archivo) as f:
    df.to_hdf(hdf_nombre_archivo, 'df',format='table')

print("")

with h5py.File(hdf_nombre_archivo) as f:
    df_nuevo = pd.read_hdf(hdf_nombre_archivo, 'df',where= ['A' < 1])

print(df_nuevo )


def Fin():
print(" ")
print("FIN")


if __name__ == "__main__":
test_conected()
Fin()
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

I have been investigating but I dont get to solve this error. Some idea?

Thanks

Angel

Answer (score 0):

where= ['A' < 1]

in your condition statement 'A' is consider as string or char and 1 is int so first make them in same type by typecasting.
ex: 
str(1)

Comment: So, I must use: df_nuevo = pd.read_hdf(hdf_nombre_archivo, 'df',where= ['A' < str(1)])  , true?

Comment: I have tried it but I get the error: VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Comment: yes you can do it.  ['A' < str(1)]) is return result as Boolean.

Comment: I have tried and I get two errors:   1- VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
Columns: [A, B, C, F]       2-  Index: []
  self.coordinates = np.arange(start, stop)[where]

Comment: If you comparing value of A with 1 then first retrieve value of A and try to make condition using value.
and you get error because of read_hdf method has arg where is not boolen and condition returns boolean.

Comment: Do you mean I must to import column A into a Dataframe and then to apply condition?

Comment: yes you can do it by add column or fetch value of A from you defined it.